# Cutting off power to Mechanical Keyboard on sleep mode to turn off LEDs

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, sleep

Keyboard: Drop CTRL
OS: Win 10 Pro

When my keyboard has it's LEDs on, when entering sleep mode, it will wake up my computer.
I have disabled the LEDs and it doesn't wake up the computer.

Is there any way to cut off power entirely to the keyboard?
It tried the various options in Device Manager but it didn't work.

Comment: There are USB hubs that support switching single ports via software. A USB relay would be another option.

Comment: @mashuptwice That's a very last option but thanks!
Maybe just a simple hub will prevent the keyboard from staying awake.

Comment: If the port the hub is connected to is powered, the hub and its ports will also be powered. Some mainboards support switching off USB ports when in S3. Check your BIOS. Alternatively [here](https://github.com/mvp/uhubctl) you can find a list of USB hubs that support power switching, although you need to check if one of them is compatible with windows.